# Smooth transition between 2 joined animations

Tags: animation

First animation try.

I have finally managed to find a way to join 2 sperate animations taken from Miximo into Blender by copying the keyframes of the first one in the second one.

However, as you can see the transition between them is quite rough and visible.  Is there a  way to make the transition between one animation and another more smooth?

[video of animation](https://1drv.ms/v/s!AqX7-zY3BAGZ_HrZvU61d7iOwAAa?e=Ja7nqq)

[image]

Comment: your animation is baked (one keyframe per frame) which doesn't make the things easy. But what you can do first is selecting all the the X and Y position from frame 212 to the end in order to bring it back at the same position as 211. Also what you could consider is selecting frame 212 and beyond to move them further in the timeline in order to make a gap between 211 and 212, and create all the intermediate images. But maybe share your file so that we can give a try?

Comment: Try to smooth the curves in the Graph Editor.

Comment: I did not understand the x and y position from frame 212 part sorry but this is still my first attempt at animation and I do not know how to eventually do it.  I tried to leave a gap as you told me and it work but I believe it still could be better, even the position between one animation ant the other is not that right.  I have uploaded the file if you want to have a look.  Thanks.